# djangorestframework-simplejwt getting "No active account found with the given credentials" although I know my user exists

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm fairly new to Django and feel I must be missing something. I have an application where I want two user types (UserType1 and UserType2). I am using the base user model with boolean flags and then created OneToOne fields on these objects to the user (no extra data added at this point).

This gives me the following user models:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel


class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Default user model for the platform
    """
    email = models.EmailField()
    is_user_type_1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_user_type_2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # Use default UserManager for now
    objects = UserManager()


class UserType1(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        related_name='user_type1',
    )


class UserType2(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
        related_name='user_type2'
    )
```

I then wrote serializes for these classes where I only want to expose and endpoint for `UserType1` and `UserType2` (rather than `User` itself). This should allow the users to create an instance of `UserType1` or `UserType2` which will also create the row in the `User` table (although maybe not super important for this). Here are the serializers:

```
from django.db import transaction
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import User, UserType1, UserType2


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for the `User` model
    """

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'is_active',
        )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}


class UserType1Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserType1
        fields = (
            'user',
            'created',
            'modified',
        )

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user_data.is_user_type_1 = True
        user_data.is_user_type_2 = False
        user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)

        user_type_1, created = UserType1.objects.update_or_create(
            user=user,
        )

        return user_type_1

class UserType2Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserType2
        fields = (
            'user',
            'created',
            'modified',
        )

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user_data.is_user_type_1 = False
        user_data.is_user_type_2 = True
        user = UserSerializer.create(UserSerializer(), validated_data=user_data)

        user_type2, created = UserType2.objects.update_or_create(
            user=user,
        )

        return user_type2
```

The `User` model was registered in my settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.User'
```

After I create a superuser, I am successfully able to get my tokens and use them to access other views:

```
{
    "refresh": "xxxx",
    "access": "xxxx"
}
```

However, if I create a user from admin (or I have fixtures that create users and user_type1/user_type2 objects), every time I try to get the tokens I am getting:

```
{
    "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"
}
```

but I know they exist in the DB since I can see them properly in the admin console. I thought this was something to do with hashing of the password but was unable to solve it.

This also contains the following `admin.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import User, UserType1, UserType2

admin.site.register(User)
admin.site.register(UserType1)
admin.site.register(UserType2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you show the admin.py file where the custom User model is registered? I guess the passwords are not being hashed, but in plain text.

Comment: Yes sorry, just edited to add above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your custom User model in the admin with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.register(models.User, UserAdmin)
```

Or follow the documentation on how to register a custom User model in admin.
[A full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)

create a new User via admin panel and check if the password is hashed.
Then make the api call to your jwt endpoint again.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Took some playing around with the fixture to seed in data but that solved it and was a huge help :)

Marked as accepted and tried to upvote but my reputation is too low